# Eclipse Cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've searched the site but still didn't found any answers to my question. Could you tell me please why mapa cannot be resolved here?

```
       mapa.setSatelite(true);
```

Here is the whole activity code:

```
  package rs.iz.stevy.wifi;

  import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuInflater;
  import android.view.MenuItem;


  public class WiFiKupacicaActivity extends MapActivity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    MapView mapa= (MapView) findViewById(R.id.Mapa1);
    mapa.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapa.setSatellite(false);

List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapa.getOverlays();
Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green);//dodaj neki marker
MapOverlay itemizedoverlay = new  MapOverlay(drawable, this);

GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(42444210,19249269);
OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Krug", "ESSID:nije utvrdjeno Šifra:ima");

GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(42441818,19263582);
OverlayItem overlayitem2 = new OverlayItem(point2, "Carine 1", "ESSID:Carine Šifra:nema");

GeoPoint point3= new GeoPoint(42442169,19261555);
OverlayItem overlayitem3 = new OverlayItem(point3, "Sejdefa", "ESSID:Sejdefa Šifra:ima");

GeoPoint point4= new GeoPoint(42440254,19250805);
OverlayItem overlayitem4 = new OverlayItem(point4, "Unico", "ESSID:Unico Šifra:ima");

GeoPoint point5= new GeoPoint(42441559,19247810);
OverlayItem overlayitem5 = new OverlayItem(point5,"Carine 2","ESSID:Carine Šfira:nema");

GeoPoint point6= new GeoPoint(42433342,19267099);
OverlayItem overlayitem6 = new OverlayItem(point6,"Forma", "ESSID:Forma Šifra:ima");

GeoPoint point7= new GeoPoint(42443596,19247948);
OverlayItem overlayitem7 = new OverlayItem(point7,"Maxim Caffe", "ESSID:nije utvrdjeno Šifra:ima");

GeoPoint point8= new GeoPoint(42449978,19259390);
OverlayItem overlayitem8 = new OverlayItem(point8,"Me Gusta","ESSID:nije utvrdjeno Šifra:nema");

GeoPoint point9= new GeoPoint(42445312,19263691);
OverlayItem overlayitem9 = new OverlayItem(point9,"Pub 013","ESSID:nije utvrdjeno Šifra:nema");

GeoPoint point10= new GeoPoint(42441254,19259972);
OverlayItem overlayitem10 = new OverlayItem(point10,"Alan Ford","ESSID:nije utvrdjeno Šifra:ima");

GeoPoint point11= new GeoPoint(42446926,19263325);
OverlayItem overlayitem11 = new OverlayItem(point11,"MNNews- Gimnazija","ESSID:nije utvrdjeno Šifra:nema/login preko web-a");

GeoPoint point12= new GeoPoint(42441257,19262810);
OverlayItem overlayitem12 = new OverlayItem(point12,"MNNews- Trg Republike","ESSID:nije utvrdjeno Šifra:nema/login preko web-a");

GeoPoint point13= new GeoPoint(42442612,19262810);
OverlayItem overlayitem13 = new OverlayItem(point13,"MNNews- Rimski trg","ESSID:nije utvrdjeno Šifra:nema/login preko web-a");



itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem2);
itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem3);
itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem4);
itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem5);
itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem6);
itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem7);
itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem8);
itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem9);
itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem10);
itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem11);
itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem12);
itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem13);

mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);

}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}



public boolean OnCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater= getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.prva:
       mapa.setSatelite(true);
        return true;
    case R.id.druga:
        //
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapa should be declared as a field in the class. 
You declare it as a variable in the onCreate method.

Comment: Could you explain me how to declare it as field instead of a variable?

Comment: That's easy. Just move the declaration of the MapView to right after the class opening bracket: private MapView mapa; You can then instantiate it in the onCreate: mapa = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.Mapa1);

Answer (score 1):

The MapView is part of an external Maps library. Make sure you have that Google API Addon.

More details here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html